# Git copy from branch to master and save all commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

[image]

I want to copy `x-y-z` to master, so in result it would be `a-b-c-d-x-y-z`

I've found two solutions:

1. `Git merge`, but my `x-y-z` become 1 merged commit, which isn't what I want.
2. `Git cherry-pick`, but I need to do it for every commit in secondary branch. Cherry-pick x, then cherry-pick y and then z. Which is too complicated.

So, is it way to do some "copy" method to achieve result as on scheme before?

Comment: You can cherry pick a range of commits.. => [How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)

Comment: This is called a rebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the correct answer is cherry-pick with range. First you need to remember commits SHA-code first. Checkout to you secondary branch and type `git log -5`. Then checkout master. And use cherry-pick with params latest commit with `^` to include it and earliest commit of range:

`git cherry-pick (SHA-code of z)^..(SHA-code of x)`

In case you have a conflict, solve it and type

`git cherry-pick --continue`

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't pushed `x-y-z` branch to remote you can do `git rebase master`.  This wouldn't "copy", but rather "move" x-y-z commits on top of `d` commit. You'd lose exact time and date of the commits as well as their sha hashes should change because what `rebase` effectively does is replays your commits on top of the `d` commit.

Comment: Yes, rebase updates my branch on top of master. But what to do next?

Comment: Nothing. you got what you wanted: x-y-z commits on top of a-b-c-d.

Comment: But I need them in master.

Comment: afterwards do `git merge master --ff-only`

Comment: In this case `git checkot master` and `git merge task_branch --ff-only`. This also works, thank you for your advice.